# Selly.gg API Help C#

Tags: c#, selly-api

I use that code to get the order's status code, order's value. But it have some error, it has been forbidden. How can I fix this problem?

```cs
private HttpResponseMessage TheOrderContent;
private HttpClient TheGetOrderHttpClient;
private HttpRequestMessage TheGetOrderHttpRequest;

TheGetOrderHttpClient = new HttpClient();
TheGetOrderHttpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://selly.gg/api/v2/orders/d453efd6-db5b-4b59-83ca-3400862a55e3");
TheGetOrderHttpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic " + {MyAPIKeyThenICanNotShow});
TheOrderContent = await TheGetOrderHttpClient.SendAsync(TheGetOrderHttpRequest);
Console.WriteLine(TheOrderContent.ToString());
```

Error Code : 403 - Forbidden! Help!

Comment: You probably need a space after `Basic` otherwise the header will contain `BasicABCDEF123456....`

Comment: Oh yeah I have added but it do not work too.

Comment: Just checking but your `MyAPIKeyThenICanNotShow` is a base 64 encoded string of `email:apikey` ?  https://developer.selly.gg/#introduction

Comment: I know that. I encoded that at base64! The rawdata is : ```Myemail@gmail.com:MyApiKey```

Comment: Can you show us how you encoded it? There are several ways of encoding strings to base64 in different formats.

Comment: https://developer.selly.gg/#errors - "401 Unauthorized - Unable to authenticate", "403 Forbidden - The request is not allowed" - the user is probably not allowed to view the order?

Comment: Oh yeah, I encoded it at this website : https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: That order is from my product. Why I can't view it?

Comment: Another, can I encoded base64 this rawdata : ```Myemail@gmail.com:MyApiKeyFromMySettings``` Will it work? Or I must remove the ```@gmail.com```?